# How to draw images about linear system?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm typing notes about linear system, but I can't draw images in it, could anyone show me how to draw them? Thank you very much[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbuCG.png)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: Also, if you search for *flow chart* on the site here, you'll probably find a few hundred examples.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. oh, thanks the same, I will try soon!